# Duplicate elements in UITableView per section

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have 6 sections in a UItableView, every section displays 2 cells, normally, I want it like this:
[image]

However, here is what I have:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/iGoMpTK.png]

Every indexPath.row is duplicated in every section.
Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"avenir";
    Avenir *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell) {
        cell =[[Avenir alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     cell.equipea.text=[arrayofClubA objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

     cell.equipeb.text=[arrayofClubB objectAtIndex:indexPath.section ];


return cell;
```

}

The elements are retrieved from two NSMutableArrays, one for the first left element in cell and the other for the right element cell.
What is wrong?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: +1 for including screen shot of drawing done by your cat

Comment: @matt: LOL! The important thing that you understood what's my problem :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the correct index from both the `row` and the `column`. Since you have two pairs of rows per section, you need to multiply `section` by two, and add `row`, which will be either zero or one. The end result should look like this:

```
NSUinteger pos = indexPath.section*2 + indexPath.row;
cell.equipea.text=[arrayofClubA objectAtIndex:pos];
cell.equipeb.text=[arrayofClubB objectAtIndex:pos];
```

Comment: I would NEVER EVER know that without your help. Millions of thanks. 2 days with that problem :/. Thank you very much.

Comment: What to do if the number of rows per section is different(not 2 like the posted question), please see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299453/wrong-cells-values-of-uitableview-per-section/17300044?noredirect=1#17300044 Thank you for answering it.

Answer (score 0):

You're always fetching the identical text for each section, since

```
cell.equipea.text=[arrayofClubA objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

always returns the same value for each section (since indexPath.section contains the section's index). Perhaps you wanted to do to the following instead?

```
cell.equipea.text=[arrayofClubA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Also, for these kind of uses, it might be a lot more straight forward to use the free Sensible TableView framework as it automatically handles displaying your arrays.