# Wrong cells values of UITableView per section

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITableView that **has a different rows count in every section**.
I made that code to try achieving a correct result:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"channel";
    ChannelsCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell) {
        cell =[[ChannelsCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    NSInteger  rowsCountSection = [[arrayofChannelsCount objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] intValue];// this variable has the number of rows of every section

    NSUInteger pos = indexPath.section*count+ indexPath.row;

    cell.channelName.text=[arrayofChannelName objectAtIndex:pos];

    return cell;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's a mathematic problem.

Thank you for helping.

EDITED:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayofChannelsOffsets=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[arrayofChannelsCount count]];
    NSNumber* zero = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];
    [arrayofChannelsOffsets addObject:zero];

    for (int j=1; j<[arrayofChannelsCount count]; j++) {
            NSUInteger sum=(int)[arrayofChannelsOffsets objectAtIndex:j-1]+(int)[arrayofChannelsCount objectAtIndex:j-1];
            NSNumber* num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:sum];
            [arrayofChannelsOffsets addObject:num];

            NSLog(@"%lu count offset:",(unsigned long)[arrayofChannelsOffsets count]);
            }

        for (int i= 0 ; i < indexPath.section ; i++) {
            pos =[[arrayofChannelsOffsets objectAtIndex:i] intValue] + indexPath.row;
               }
        cell.channelName.text=[arrayofChannelName objectAtIndex:pos];
```

I have strange error:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 267575552 beyond bounds [0 .. 101]'
```

From where that huge number 267575552 did come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, you need to total up the number of rows in all sections prior to this one rather than using `indexPath.section*count`:

```
NSUInteger pos = indexPath.row;
for (int = 0 ; i < indexPath.section ; i++) {
    pos += [[arrayofChannelsCount objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}
cell.channelName.text=[arrayofChannelName objectAtIndex:pos];
```

Note that the code is somewhat redundant: it repeats the same calculations over and over for each cell. You can add a new `NSArray *arrayofChannelsOffsets` which has the same number of items as `arrayofChannelsCount`, but rather than containing the individual count, each item should contain the sum of counts in the sections less than the current one. With an array like that you'd be able to avoid the loop by writing

```
NSUInteger pos = [[arrayofChannelsOffsets objectAtIndex:i] intValue] + indexPath.row;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is 90% solved. I don't know why it begins with the first(1) element of arrayofChannelName and not with the 0 element(I'll try later to to optimise the code like you noticed).

Comment: @androniennn I think I made a mistake - replacing `<=` in the loop with `<` in the loop should fix the problem.

Comment: Big Respect man ! You're the best like always :). And now I'll more optimise the code like you told me. Thank you very very very much, you make my day :).

Comment: For the second case, I'm trying to code something, when doing a manual execution it seems that the results in the UITableView will be reversed, no? For example if I have 100 as the sum of all sections rows count, and the first item in CountArray is 2, so the first item in OffsetArray will be 98(100-2). `cell.channelName.text=[arrayofChannelName objectAtIndex:99];` it'll contain the last 2 elements of the array, and I expect to have the 2 first ones. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @androniennn Let's say your `arrayofChannelsCount` is `{2, 4, 4, 2, 5}`. Then your `arrayofChannelsOffsets` should be `{0, 2, 6, 10, 12}`. In other words, `arrayofChannelsOffsets[0]` must be zero, and then for `i` at `1` or above `arrayofChannelsOffsets[i]` should be `arrayofChannelsOffsets[i-1] + arrayofChannelsCount[i-1]`.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll test it right now, I'll tell you the results later :).

Comment: Can you please see my edited post? I have added a code and want to show it to you (I'll remove it later)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Refer [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: The problem is not the number of rows in section, but the rows' values